# How do I cast a character column in R

Tags: r, reshape

Using a data frame like this

```
df <- data.frame(Season=c("1992","1993","1993"),
               Team=c("Man Utd.","Blackburn","Blackburn"),
               Player=c("Peter Schmeichel(42)","Tim Flowers(39)","Bobby Mimms(4)"),
               Order = c(1,1,2))
```

How do i get to this

```
   1992  Man Utd. Peter Schmeichel(42)     
   1993 Blackburn      Tim Flowers(39)  Bobby Mimms(4)
```

Comment: You should clarify if you want those to be separate column (as in @Joran's answer) or collapsed as in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df,Season+Team~Order,value.var = "Player")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(Season, Team), summarize, Players = paste(Player, collapse = " "))

#-----
  Season      Team                        Players
1   1992  Man Utd.           Peter Schmeichel(42)
2   1993 Blackburn Tim Flowers(39) Bobby Mimms(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sticking in base R, you can do the following:

```
aggregate(list(Player = df$Player), 
          list(Season = df$Season, Team = df$Team), paste)
#   Season      Team                          Player
# 1   1993 Blackburn Tim Flowers(39), Bobby Mimms(4)
# 2   1992  Man Utd.            Peter Schmeichel(42)
```

#### Update

Having seen your desired output from the accepted answer, note that this is also possible using base R's `reshape()` function:

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar=c("Season", "Team"), timevar="Order")
#   Season      Team             Player.1       Player.2
# 1   1992  Man Utd. Peter Schmeichel(42)           <NA>
# 2   1993 Blackburn      Tim Flowers(39) Bobby Mimms(4)
```

Comment: thanks for these suggestions. Do you know how  I can obtain a left alignment in the column for either alternative?

Comment: @pssguy, why would you need to do that in R? If you *really* do need to format it in R, see the help file for `format()` at `?format`. You would need to first make sure that the data are *character* and not *factor* in order for the `justify` argument to take effect though.

Comment: Thanks. I want to print the results as a table for a web site. I normally use the gplots package but although the format() works in R it does not translate to the final image. Do you know of an alternative approach, by any chance

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `tidyr

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df,Order,Player)
```